# d3.js equivalent to columns in R dataframes

Tags: r, d3.js

I have some data stored in this format (except many cases more):

```
var data = [
     {"name":"John", "team":"team1"},
     {"name":"Megan", "team":"team2"},
     {"name":"Rupert", "team":"team2"},
     {"name":"Albert", "team":"team1"}
     ];
```

I want to create this:

```
var colourScale = d3.scale.ordinal() 
  .range(a)
  .domain(b)
```

"a" being an array of all levels of "team" (i.e. ["team1","team2"] in this case).
"b" being an array of ordinal colours of the same length as "a".
colourScale() should take the "team"-value as input and return a unique colour for each team.

How do I create "a" and "b"? Is there something equivalent to R's levels(data[ ,"team"]) in javascript or d3.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly your solution as you don't explicitly find your specified `a` or `b`, but I found

```
var colourScale = d3.scale.category10();
function colour(d) { return d.team; }
```

and on the object you want to colour, bound to the appropriate data, chain

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return colourScale(colour(d)); });
```

has the effect that I assume you're searching for. Hope this helps.

Comment: great, this is easier than the solution I had in mind. I successfully implemented it. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Bare in mind that if you need more than 10 colours, you can use category20, otherwise you'll need to look for a more general method.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some extra steps you need to do. You need first to create a 'unique' set of possible domain values. Then you can create a function that maps each value to a color. Something like this perhaps:

```
// A function to get unique values, can be optimized further
function unique(x) {
    return x.reverse().filter(function (e, i, x) {return x.indexOf(e, i+1) === -1;}).reverse();
}

var data = [
 {"name":"John", "team":"team1"},
 {"name":"Megan", "team":"team2"},
 {"name":"Rupert", "team":"team2"},
 {"name":"Albert", "team":"team1"}
 ];

// An arbitrary set of colors
colors = ['#005824','#1A693B','#347B53','#4F8D6B','#699F83','#83B09B','#9EC2B3','#B8D4CB','#D2E6E3','#EDF8FB','#FFFFFF','#F1EEF6','#E6D3E1','#DBB9CD','#D19EB9','#C684A4','#BB6990','#B14F7C','#A63467','#9B1A53','#91003F']

//Create the ordinary scale based on your color set above
colorScale= d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(unique(data.map(function(d){return d.team;})))
   .range(colors)
```

Then you can access the color by:

```
.style("fill",function(d){return colorScale(d.team);})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, this is the solution as I thought of it. Seems like javascript works a little different than what I'm used to in R.

Comment: Yes. It needs some getting used to. I am an R user myself so I understand the difficulty.